# Revolution Pi wifi doesn't connect unless WiFi dongle is manually reconnected

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a Revolution Pi connected via WiFi dongle. 
Network is configured properly in wpa_supplicant.conf .

I have a script that is running on my program's startup that restarts the interface (ifconfig down, ifconfig up, restart to dhcpcd service).

After the interface restart, my interface doesn't reconnect to my WiFi. 
The ifconfig output shows an IP address, but the iwconfig is showing "unassociated". Every attempt to connect from wpa_cli fails.

The only thing that gets me back online is to physically disconnect and reconnect the WiFi dongle.

Did anyone encounter this behavior before?

adding configuration output to maybe clarify the issue:
**wlan0 commands output (with censored addresses):**

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet **<ipv4 address>**  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast **<BC ipv4>**
    inet6 **ipv6 address**  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 **ipv6 address**  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 **ipv6 address**  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether **MAC address**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 60  bytes 10493 (10.2 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 13  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 36  bytes 6783 (6.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Problematic commands + resulting issue: **

```
root@hostname:~# ifconfig wlan0 down
root@hostname:~# ifconfig wlan0 up

root@hostname:~# ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether **<MAC address>**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 256599 (250.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 51  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 8429 (8.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@hostname:~# iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: What is a Revolution Pi? If network is configured properly it must work!

Comment: Its a raspberry pi meant for harsher conditions than usual (industries etc.)  . 
I know that the configs are fine because when I manually reconnect the dongle everything works perfect.. The ifconfig down & up makes it fail..

Comment: You can use `dhcpcd` (which I recommend) or fiddle with Debian networking. Attempting to do both is futile. Without knowing what you actually do this is just a rant.

Comment: Not knowing anything about Revolution Pi, I'd say check which commands are run when you plug in the adapter, and run these same commands at startup.

Comment: @Milliways What do you mean by "without knowing what you actually do"? If you mean what my program does - its irrelevant.. Even if I dont run anything and just issue a "ifconfig wlan0 down" and then "ifconfig wlan0 up", the RPi won't reconnect to my wifi. When physically reconnecting the dongle - works just fine.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Thanks. The RevPi isn't much different from a standard RaspPi.. How would I go about checking which commands are run when I plug in the adapter?

Comment: AFAIK regular RPi with Raspbian doesn't have the problem that you describe, so your device seems to be different enough.

Comment: The difference that might cause the issue is that the revPi uses an external WiFi adapter.. Is there a way to see what's running when I connect the adapter ?